# Density of subset with nonlocal boundary condition

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis, stochastic-processes

I am having difficulty proving that $E=\bigcap_{n\geq 0} \{f\in C^2 (\mathbb{R}) :f(0)=\sum_{k\geq 0} f(\frac{k}{\sqrt{n}})g_n (k)\}$ is a dense subset of:
$F=\{f\in C^2 (\mathbb{R}) : f(0)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(u)g(u)du\}$

By assumption, we are given the fact that $\lim_{n}\sum_{k\geq 0} f(\frac{k}{\sqrt{n}})g_n (k)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(u)g(u)du$, where $g_n$ and $g$ are probability density functions.

My initial idea was to consider $f_n (x) = f(x)+\sum_{k\geq 0} f(\frac{k}{\sqrt{n}})g_n (k)-\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(u)g(u)du$. In this case, we would obviously have $\lim_{n} f_n=f$, but the problem is $f_n$ is not necessarily in $E$.
Any help or references to relevant literature would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Essentially, the difficulty lies in the fact that if $f\in F$, I have to construct a sequence of functions $f_n$ converging to $f$ with $f_n$ satisfying the nonlocal "discrete" boundary condition. I have also thought about Taylor expansions about $0$ but this doesn't seem to help either!